# Node.JS/socket.io and safari

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, safari, socket.io

I have a node.js software that use [socket.io 1.3.0](http://socket.io/) lib for communication between client and server.
In my architecture the server is behind a proxy nginx.
I test the software with all last browser version. 
Everything works except when i use Safari (last version). 
I read that Safari uses an earlier version of the protocol WebSocket (hixie-76).
My question is: there is a way to change in socket.io the protocol version when i use Safari browser?

This is my nginx (1.7.12) configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://internalhost:8080/;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your nginx configuration for webSocket?

Comment: Multi-line text like your config is not readable in comments.  Please use the edit link below your question and add this to your question and format it appropriately.

Comment: I update previous post